# Jquery not working in include php file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery menu in `header.php`. if i include header.php file in `index.php` file the jquery not working.

**header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdowncontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ddmegamenu.js"></script>
<script>
ddmegamenu.docinit({
menuid:'course',
dur:800,
easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
})
</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<body>
<div id="mainwrapper">
<?php require_once( "../header.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your `head` tag? Also, you probably want to `$(document).ready()` that `ddmegamnu` call.

Comment: It's really hard to say from your example.  Does it all work if you just have the JavaScript in the index.php file directly?

Comment: Check your console for errors, make sure all the files requested within script tags are being loaded!

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script>
 ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'course',
    dur:800,
    easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
 })
 </script>
```

I am not sure what is it doing, but keep this code inside `document.ready` event handler to trigger,

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'course',
    dur:800,
    easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
   })
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP include you are changing directories. Make sure your `<script src="">` tags reflects that change.

Are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdowncontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ddmegamenu.js"></script>
```

in the same directory as `header.php` or `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a js syntax error, you forgot to end your docinit function with a ;.  Also, make sure you wrap your jQuery inside of the document ready function or it might run before the DOM is ready.  Here's a working example.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    ddmegamenu.docinit({
        menuid:'course',
        dur:800,
        easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
    })
});
</script>
```

Assuming that is the correct jQuery, it should probably run.

If not, make sure you are including a php file in a different directory, that might be your problem. I would say make sure you are including the javascript files correctly.  View the source and click on the src URLs to verify.  The src="" you have used below are pointing to a relative path, in this case in the current directory, so your dropdowncontent.js and ddmegamenu.js must be in the same directory as your index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdowncontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ddmegamenu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your page and check `console` in `firebug` to view what are the possible reasons why your script is not running. else there is no reason in your code to not run. it should run. Maybe the js file you are trying to include do not present in the same directory where your index and header files present. also try changing your js like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ //add document.ready()
   ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'course',
    dur:800,
    easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by including the JS files before the < /body > tag almost at the end of the layout I was using.